# How to get the bool variable in the default case i.e "false"

Tags: c#

I have the following method:

```
    private String getLicenseID(String arglicenseID, bool istrue)
    {
        String licenseID = arglicenseID;

        if (licenseID != null)
        {
            licenseID =  licenseID + " " + istrue;
        }
        return licenseID;
    }
```

When I call the function I pass `istrue` as false.

The problem is that while debugging, `istrue` has the value "false" (note that "f" is lowercase), but when I inspect the returned value of `licenseID`, I see the `licenseID` concatenated with value "False" ("F" is uppercase).

My requirement is to get `licenseID` + "false". Although I can change the case after getting the string, is there any other solution available? Could someone explain to me why it is happening?

Comment: Best name for boolean parameter ever :p

Comment: That's just how debugger and bool.toString() are implemented. If you need an all lowercase string representation, you have to deal with that yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

True and False are the normal [string conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/atahsch6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the boolean values in .net. What you are seeing (true and false) are the debugger values. Just use the `ToLower` method on the string converted boolean.

> This method returns the constants "True" or "False". Note that XML is
>   case-sensitive, and that the XML specification recognizes "true" and
>   "false" as the valid set of Boolean values. If the String object
>   returned by the ToString() method is to be written to an XML file, its
>   String.ToLower method should be called first to convert it to
>   lowercase.

Answer (score 4):

Just convert your `bool` variable to string and use `string.ToLower` method:

```
 licenseID += " " + istrue.ToString().ToLower();
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't rely on the automatic string conversion. Instead, just write what you need:

```
(isTrue ? "true" : "false")
```

(Ideally, you'd have a helper method do that for you, or you'd use constants instead of string literals)

This stems from the fact that IL's bool has values `True` and `False`. The lowercase variants are C#'s keywords, and they are basically aliases for the "real" bool values.

You can see the same thing happening when you do e.g. `string.GetType().Name` - `string` is the C# alias for a type named `System.String`.